# Create a full string from the content of a string iterator as it is being consumed

Tags: python, asynchronous, iterator, generator, fastapi

I am creating a backend API that uses LangChain to send user messages to and stream responses back from an LLM.

The endpoint that sends responses to the frontend uses a FastAPI `StreamingResponse`.

The streamed LLM response is held in the following Pydantic model:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from collections.abc import AsyncIterable

class LLMResponse(BaseModel):
    role: str
    content: AsyncIterable[str]
```

This content field is populated as follows:

```py
async def get_reponse(input: str) -> LLMResponse:
    return LLMResponse(
        role='AI',
        content=(
            chunk.content
            async for chunk in chain.astream(input)
        )
    )
```

where `chain` is a LangChain LLM chain.

The streaming response is then created and returned to the client as:

```py
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

def some_endpoint(...) -> StreamingResponse:
    ...
    return StreamingResponse(content=llm_response.content)
```

So the content `AsyncIterable` is not consumed until it is streamed from the frontend. What I would like to do is add another field to `LLMResponse` called `full_content: str` which is the full response from the LLM after it has all been streamed, so that. have access to the full response on the backend as well. This could be done as simply as:

```py
llm_response.content_full = ''.join([x for x in llm_response.content])
```

but of course the backend is then consuming the async iterable, not the frontend.

How can I get the full content of this iterable after it has been consumed by the client?